# KSH Alternative for read -a?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ksh

What is an alternative for `read -A`?

I want the User to input for- and surname but not separately (into array elements 0 and 1).

Thanks in advance.

brgds

Comment: BTW, if it's literally two elements, you don't need `read -a` or `read -A`; just `read firstname surname rest` will read the first field into `firstname`, the second into `surname`, and any additional input into `rest` (as for error checking; otherwise, such additional input would be concatenated to the surname).

Answer (score 3):

From the man page:

> ```
> read  [  -ACSprsv  ] [ -d delim] [ -n n] [ [ -N n] [ [ -t timeout] [ -u unit] [ vname?prompt ] [ vname ... ]
>       [...]The -A option causes the variable vname to be unset and  each field that is read to be stored in successive elements
>           of the indexed array vname.[...]
> ```

So it's just `read -A foo`:

```
$ read -A foo <<< "john doe"
$ printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
john
doe
```